# Why do I need to "reassign" an object of stdClass to use its value as a string?

Tags: php, object

This error :

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
$$site->nomCommission[$site->opponent][$alltheSeat->categorie] = (object) [
   'gamesDate' => $gameDate,
   'idGames' => $site->idGames
];
```

This does not :

```
$nomCommission = $site->nomCommission;

$$nomCommission[$site->opponent][$alltheSeat->categorie] = (object) [
   'gamesDate' => $gameDate,
   'idGames' => $site->idGames
];
```

Now if I dump both variables, they contain the same string obviously since they are equals. so why is one considered an object since var dump tells me they are both strings. Perhaps I should use another syntax ?

```
$nomCommission = $site->nomCommission;
string(11) "Groupe Test"
```

I got use to "renaming" my variables because it saves me time, I avoid errors  and its often cleaner to do this but depending on the project I sometimes end up renaming way to many.
 I understand one is an object (or is it ? ) but what logic should I keep in mind, when is it waste of code to rename them ?

For example, sometimes this doesn't work it throws same kind of error but in this case it does work so I am kind of confused. Share some light anyone ?

```
$$nomCommission [$site->nomCommission]
```

Comment: "its often cleaner to do this" --- nope.

Comment: _"I avoid errors"_ well,....

Comment: reading your code I have not the slightest clue of what you're doing. I think you make your life too complicated by "simplifying" things

Comment: Your code is confusing as all get out. And using variable variables `$$nomCommission` should be done sparingly, not as a default. I assume whatever class`$nomCommission` eventually is has a `__tostring()` method, which `stdClass` does not. This isn't "weird", you've just changed your object to a class that allows being cast as a string.

Comment: " I understand one is an object (or is it ? )" This is why your code pattern is a problem. You have no idea what your variable types are (and neither did we!)

Comment: @Zerkms If I am going to re-use them over and over, care to suggest anything better ?

Comment: Yep, just use variables. In most programming languages "variable variables" don't even exist, yet people write all sort of applications with them.

Comment: when i said rename thats pretty much what I meant.  using 1 variable for each of my result is often overkill

Comment: Since the answer was straight forward  ( use brackets ) and to me its a legit syntax question why the down ? so i can keep it in mind  next time I have a question I wont feel like I'm being bashed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add curly braces to force the desired parse:

```
${$site->nomCommission}[$site->opponent][$alltheSeat->categorie] = ...
```

Your code is being treated as:

```
$obj = $$site;
$obj->nonCommission[$site->opponent][$alltheSeat->categorie] = ...
```

`$$site` requires `$site` to be a string containing the name of a variable, but `$site` is an object, not a string.

That said, anything you can do with variable variables can almost always be done using associative arrays, and the syntax is more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the bracket trick ! I am actually sorting the values in an associative array, using variable variables I can easily filter my results. I also use it for operations instead of listing all the variable. For exemple if object's string value represents multiple colors  isnt $$color the way to go ?